# My past employer is talking openly to my boyfriend about my leaving the job

Tags: united-states, employment, privacy

I walked out on my position as a medical assistant. My boyfriend is still a patient there, and during his last apointment, the doctor openly talked about how wrong I was to walk out on my job. Does he have a legal right to talk to others about how I left my employment? They're already making it impossible to use as a reference as its left me with nothing but dead ends.

Comment: What state? Also, can you be more precise about what you mean when you say you "walked out" and what types of things the previous employer is saying. For example, are they saying things that are untrue? More details will help frame your question.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your employer agreed in a contract to not discuss your employment, then there is no legal restrictions on them discussing anything about your employment.  If they say things that are untrue you could sue them for defamation.

Answer (score 0):

If you contact your old HR department you can see if its illegal for him to be talking about you in a way that is effecting your life and current career, if its bad enough and you dont want to confront him about it, id say go to the eeoc website which is the US equal employment opportunity commission and file a complaint with them. I would try and get a copy of the any documents you signed when you were hired and read about your rights as an employee there. If there is nothing there that is legally binding about what he is doing to you, there might be little you can do. Id say if you have evidence it is probably illegal...also depends on what state you're in. eeoc.gov will tell you what to do.

Comment: This is advice, but it doesn't appear to be an answer to the question: "Does he have a legal right to talk to others about how I left my employment?"

Comment: Also, you need to indicate how talking about an ex-employee is related to the powers of EEOC. They aren't a generic complaint agency.